# Can I refer friends to the site while it's in private beta?

Tags: discussion

I think that people in my gaming group might be interested, and the more people post, the more we pick up momentum. However, I'm not sure whether people are allowed to sign up right now. Should I be sending them links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Maybe if they can Commit to the proposal while in beta (on area51, proposal page, tab commit), but I seriously doubt it. In any case, the site is going public in 4 days, it's not much.